# Find all elements by part of the id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if this was possible:

I have a set of divs, each with an ID ending in '_font', e.g 'body_font', 'heading_font', 'tagline_font', etc.

Is there a way to grab those elements by searching for a common portion of their names, in this case '_font' so I can later manipulate them using jQuery?

Comment: You should add a class like `font` to all such divs and select by class name. Your approach is really bad practice.

Comment: I'm aware and I normally would. But I'm using Options Framework for WordPress and it doesn't allow for this - each option has its own id.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use an ["attribute ends-with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
var elems = $("div[id$='_font']");
```

If you spend some time browsing the jQuery API you should be able to answer questions like this yourself without having to post on Stack Overflow.

Other selectors that might come in useful:

- [Attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- [Attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
- [Attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use wild cards, `$` will give you elements which have ending with give string, learn more about ends with selctor [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

```
elements = $('[id$=_font]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 var elements = $("[id$='_font']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, use:

```
var elements = $('[id$=_font]');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) should do what you are asking:

```
$("div[id$='_font']")
```